# Simulating a right join in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model `Person` that `belongsToMany` `Review` objects.

This is all working great, and I can query thing successfully.

What I'd like to do now is to query all `Person` where there isn't a `Review` associated with them.

I've tried things like

`Person::with('reviews')->whereNull('reviews.id')->get();`

and

```
Person::whereHas('reviews', function($q)
    {
        $q->whereNull('id');
    })->get();
```

but with no success - what do I need to do to just get the `Person` objects where they have no `Review` objects?

This would be very easy with normal SQL, but I have lots of other code that uses the Eloquent models, so I'd like to keep using Eloquent here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `whereDoesntHave`:

```php
Person::whereDoesntHave('reviews')->get();
```

From the [API (4.2)](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereDoesntHave)

> Add a relationship count condition to the query.

The method from **illuminate/database/Eloquent/Builder.php** (see the code [here](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php#L611)):

```php
    public function whereDoesntHave($relation, Closure $callback = null)
    {
        return $this->doesntHave($relation, 'and', $callback);
    }
```

which calls:

```php
/**
 * Add a relationship count condition to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $relation
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
 */
public function doesntHave($relation, $boolean = 'and', Closure $callback = null)
{
    return $this->has($relation, '<', 1, $boolean, $callback);
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Yes, sometimes with laravel we have to digg a bit in the API or the code itself ;-)